# How to subtract every time from the start time

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, timestamp

I have a dataframe "user1" with around 100000 rows of which some of the entries are as follows :

```
    user                    timestamp        x          y          z       class   
0      0x11      2018-04-10 12:37:51.252     -0.86      6.51        1.28        walk
1      0x11      2018-04-10 12:37:51.252     -3.16      9.52        2.98        walk
2      0x11      2018-04-10 12:37:51.324     -3.31      8.94        2.24        walk
```

Instead of full time, I want the difference between current time and the start time i.e suppose in 3rd row the timestamp is `2018-04-10 12:37:51.252`. I would like to change it to `(2018-04-10 12:37:51.252 - 2018-04-10 12:37:51.324 = 0.72 secs)`. How to do this with pandas. All the other column entries should remain as it is.

Comment: Check if this is what you want `df['timestamp'] = df['timestamp'].diff()`.

Comment: Do you need grouping by[ `user` ] or [`user` and `class`] column?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ensuring your datetime column is a datetime is the first step,

```
import numpy as np 
import pandas as pd
df['timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(df['timestamp'])
```

next, we grab the earliest timestamp record per user with `transform`

the benefit of transform is that it allows one to use `groupby` methods without modifying the index, very handy.

```
ts = df.groupby(['user'])['timestamp'].transform('min')
```

then return the delta as seconds to match your target output.

```
df['timedelta'] = (df['timestamp'] - ts) / np.timedelta64(1,'s')

print(df)

   user               timestamp     x     y     z class  timedelta
0  0x11 2018-04-10 12:37:51.252 -0.86  6.51  1.28  walk      0.000
1  0x11 2018-04-10 12:37:51.252 -3.16  9.52  2.98  walk      0.000
2  0x11 2018-04-10 12:37:51.324 -3.31  8.94  2.24  walk      0.072
```

Comment: Hey @Manakin, thanks for the answer. One more question. If there are multiple dates in the dataset, then I want the timedelta according to each date i.e. if there are 10000 rows for one specific date, then I have to calculate timedelta for that specific date, and if there are another 10000 rows for another date then I need to calculate timedelta for that date also.

Comment: What's the difference between the 10k rows? You are already grouping by user?

Answer (score 2):

If need first values per groups use [`DataFrame.transform`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.transform.html) with [`GroupBy.first`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.first.html), subtract by [`Series.sub`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.sub.html) and convert timedeltas to seconds by [`Series.dt.total_seconds`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.total_seconds.html):

```
df['timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(df['timestamp'])

#if data are sorted
s = df.groupby('user')['timestamp'].transform('first')
#if data are not sorted and need minimal
#s = df.groupby('user')['timestamp'].transform('min')
df['diff'] = df['timestamp'].sub(s).dt.total_seconds()
print (df)
   user               timestamp     x     y     z class   diff
0  0x11 2018-04-10 12:37:51.252 -0.86  6.51  1.28  walk  0.000
1  0x11 2018-04-10 12:37:51.252 -3.16  9.52  2.98  walk  0.000
2  0x11 2018-04-10 12:37:51.324 -3.31  8.94  2.24  walk  0.072
```

EDIT:

If need grouping by `user` and `class` column:

```
df['timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(df['timestamp'])

#if data are sorted
s = df.groupby(['user','class'])['timestamp'].transform('first')
#if data are not sorted and need minimal
#s = df.groupby(['user','class'])['timestamp'].transform('min')
df['diff'] = df['timestamp'].sub(s).dt.total_seconds()
print (df)
   user               timestamp     x     y     z class   diff
0  0x11 2018-04-10 12:37:51.252 -0.86  6.51  1.28  walk  0.000
1  0x11 2018-04-10 12:37:51.252 -3.16  9.52  2.98  walk  0.000
2  0x11 2018-04-10 12:37:51.324 -3.31  8.94  2.24  walk  0.072
```

Comment: I thought of using `first` too but thought the data may not always be sorted.